# How to create an irregular(not rectangle) toolips-stype popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I wonder in desktop browser(html), how to create a pop up window same as the irregular popup window of chrome plugin popup.html. In chrome plugin, when you click a plugin icon, it will show a pop up window with an arrow in its corner pointing to that icon.

Can anyone give an example on how to realize this window?

Comment: This is not a broad question. I am trying to get an IRREGULAR shape dialog box, NOT a rectangular one. I described the shape of window(dialog box) in last sentence of my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

take a look at [jquery-ui Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style)

Then, it's up to your imagination